# How to select rows by criteria connected with two tables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table with 2 columns, `"name"` and `"grade"`. In `"name"` column I store data that can be replicated couple of times. To imagine the problem, let's create a simple short table like the one below:

```
list <- data.frame(c("Natalia", "Alex", "Adam", "Natalia", "Natalia", "Alex", "Natalia", "Adam"), c(5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4))
colnames(list) <- c("name", "grade")
```

I'd like to get a `dataframe` with two columns - a list of unique data from column `"name"` in first one and with a sum of grades for each name in second.
The first column I created like that:

```
n_occur <- data.frame(table(list$name))
```

and it works - I have a column of unique names from previous table.
Unfortunately I have no idea how to count grades for each name. It's more or less sth like pseudocode below, but I don't know r syntax well, so it's a bit hard for me.

```
sum(list$grades) where (list$names == n_occur$X1)
```

I think that I should combine filter with select somehow, but I didn't manage to do that.

Comment: This is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for;

```
library(dplyr)
list%>%
   group_by(name)%>%
   summarise(sum(grade))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#     name sum(grade)
#   (fctr)      (dbl)
#1    Adam          9
#2    Alex         10
#3 Natalia         17
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. Let's say we have one more column, f.ex. number of week in which person got the grade. I'd like to group data so that for each person, for each week, I have the sum of their grades.

Comment: Actually I managed to to that, so maybe I share the solution if anyone need it in future. Firstly I changed from dataframe to data.table
`library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(list)[, by=c("name", "week", "grade")][]`
And then I used .SD like that:
`dt <- dt[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = c("week", "name")]` what gave me what I needed ;)